# Angular 7 release - custom settings per release environment via CI/CD Pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am familiar with using dotnet core in Azure Devops Pipelines.  Where we would have one **BUILD** for a project.  The same build is then **RELEASED** (promoted) to each environment (for consistency) and then any environment specific settings are in a config file appsettings.json etc.

Examples of the settings, which are different for dev/staging/uat/prod. are things like:

- API url
- base-url
- loggingserverurl

I'm trying to set up the pipeline for an Angular 7 application.   The build looks like this:
[image: Build Steps]

The ng/npm build step takes a while, so I'm reluctant to do 4-5 separate builds per environment as it feels so alien.  Am I fighting a losing battle or is there a way to do this in the release stage, just building once?

Comment: You could try to make your own `APP_INITIALIZER` provider that reads `json` file for your settings. I did something similar but I still use the `env` per build. Here's the link that I used as a reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/ You would just have to modify it so you don't use environment specific.

Comment: Do you know where the url's exist after the build? (e.g. in `main.bindle.js`)